# Can I delete SQLServer2017Media folder from my C drive?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL server 2017 on my laptop, because am running out of disk space I would like to know is it okay if I delete the **SQLServer2017Media** folder (takes 1.6 GB) now that set up us complete and application is running fine?

Installation folder is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server, but **SQLServer2017Media** folder is also in my C drive C:\SQLServer2017Media and taking up 1.61 GB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it okay if I delete the SQLServer2017Media folder (takes 1.6 GB) now that set up us complete and application is running fine?

Yes it is totally safe to delete it, this would not affect running SQL Server application. But sometimes during un-installation later or may be future installation or adding feature you may need the whole installation file. So my suggestion would be to copy it to pendrive and keep it safe if you "really" do not want to keep it on desktop or any other drive on your PC. Plus would it not be possible to move it to other drive on your PC ( ofcourse if you have one then) ?